# ACF Taxonomy field values not select in backend

Tags: php, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, advanced-custom-fields

I created delivery type field using ACF taxonomy. And its working finecheck

[image: screenshot 1]
but I need to add this field in my website product add page.

I used some hardcode in my theme funtion.php to show the delivery type field in product add page.

here is the code-

```
  <div>
Please enter Delivery Type "Free Of Delivery Or Delivery charges Apply"

</div>
//dtype
 <?php if ( dokan_get_option( 'product_category_style', 'dokan_selling', 'single' ) == 'single' ): ?>
                                    <div class="dokan-form-group">

                                        <?php
                                        $selected_dtype  = dokan_posted_input( 'delivery_types' );
                                        $dtype_args =  array(
                                            'show_option_none' => __( '- Select a Delivery types  -', 'dokan-lite' ),
                                            'hierarchical'     => 1,
                                            'hide_empty'       => 0,
                                            'name'             => 'delivery_types',
                                            'id'               => 'delivery_types',
                                            'taxonomy'         => 'delivery_types',
                                            'title_li'         => '',
                                            'class'            => 'product_cat dokan-form-control dokan-select2',
                                            'exclude'          => '',
                                            'selected'         => $selected_dtype  ,
                                        );

                                        wp_dropdown_categories( apply_filters( 'dokan_product_cat_dropdown_args', $dtype_args ) );
                                        ?>
                                    </div>

                                <?php elseif ( dokan_get_option( 'product_category_style', 'dokan_selling', 'single' ) == 'multiple' ): ?>
                                    <div class="dokan-form-group">
                                        <?php

                                        include_once DOKAN_LIB_DIR.'/class.taxonomy-walker.php';

                                        $selected_dtype  = dokan_posted_input( 'delivery_types', true );
                                        $selected_dtype  = empty( $selected_dtype  ) ? array() : $selected_dtype  ;

                                        $drop_down_dtype = wp_dropdown_categories( apply_filters( 'dokan_product_cat_dropdown_args', array(
                                            'show_option_none' => __( '', 'dokan-lite' ),
                                            'hierarchical'     => 1,
                                            'hide_empty'       => 0,
                                            'name'             => 'delivery_types[]',
                                            'id'               => 'delivery_types',
                                            'taxonomy'         => 'delivery_types',
                                            'title_li'         => '',
                                            'class'            => 'product_cat dokan-form-control dokan-select2',
                                            'exclude'          => '',
                                            'selected'         => $selected_dtype,
                                            'echo'             => 0,
                                            'walker'           => new TaxonomyDropdown()
                                        ) ) );

                                        echo str_replace( '<select', '<select data-placeholder="'.esc_attr__( 'Select Delivery types', 'dokan-lite' ).'" multiple="multiple" ', $drop_down_dtype ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.XSS.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped
                                        ?>
                                    </div>
                                <?php endif; ?>
```

But the issue is its not save in back end.[image: (check screenshot 1)]

My ACF settings

Check Screenshot 2
[image]

Check screenshot 3
[image]

if someone can help me really appreciate because I'm stuck in this issue in over month.

thank you.

Comment: You'll have to open a ticket with ACF (if you haven't already) as this is a third party plugin and as such is considered off topic. It's entirely possible that someone may provide you with an answer here but it'd probably be better to ask the source, the ACF development team.

Comment: ok my friend i will do it.